# How to config a cache to point to local ehcache instead of inherited one?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am trying to use a local ehcache created in my project declared through ehcache.xml file and configured through CacheManager, but am unable to do that and can only use the inherited cache.

Is there a way I can use the cache I declare in the local ehcache.xml file? Please help

I want to create a local Ehcache to store my method results.
My cache config file is below

```
@Configuration
@Component
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@Primary
public class CacheConfig extends cacheProcessor {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }
}
```

It is trying to override the cache config file defined in the project brought in through dependency because I want to point it to a local ehcache.xml with a new cache name.

My local ehcache.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
        name="timePass"
        updateCheck="false"
        monitoring="autodetect"
        dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <cache name="newCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
```

The application class file has a component scan annotation to the inherited projects as well.

My caching service looks like this:

```
@Component
@Service

public class cacheableService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "newCache")
    public Collection<ObjectDTO> getAllData(){
        return a new list logic
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error, that it cannot find the cache name I have mentioned in the Cacheable annotation, which is the one I declare in the local XML file. And when I use a cache name i.e. in declared in the inherited project ehcache.xml file, it finds the cache.

I have already set the following properties in the application.yml file

```
spring.cache.ehcache.config.classpath = ehcache.xml
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true
```